# What is the complexification of the $n$-sphere $S^n$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

> What is the complexification of the $n$-sphere $S^n$ under the construction given in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/306765/how-does-one-complexify-a-real-n-dimensional-riemannian-manifold-m-g)? Does such a construction exist?

I do not think it would be $\mathbb{CP}^{n/2}$, as this is not a contractible space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The construction is that of Bruhat-Whitney, given [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=In1Dbj-pkIkC&pg=PA103&dq=complexification+of+real+analytic+manifolds&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aYRAUrWeBYPZ2AWEj4DoBA#v=onepage&q=complexification%20of%20real%20analytic%20manifolds&f=false) as Thm 5.41. They only say that the complexification is unique in a small neighborhood of $M$ in $M^{\Bbb C}$, so it seems that these small neighborhoods must be what one means when they say "the complexification".

Comment: Then the final comment on that page is what you need: "Note that a sufficiently small complexification $M^{\Bbb C}$ is as a real manifold diffeomorphic to $TM$". So $(S^n)^{\Bbb C}$ is diffeomorphic to $TS^n$, which is diffeomorphic to $S^n \times S^n \setminus \Delta$ (where $\Delta$ is the diagonal, the set of points of the form $(x,x)$.)

Comment: Thanks as always! @MikeMiller